# React component reference own DOM-element in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

Still being quite new to React I've run across the following issue:
I'm creating a component this way:

```
export const CSpiderWeb = (props: iSpiderWebProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [drawingObject, setDrawingObject] = useState({} as iDrawingObject);

    const _InitRaphael = (target : HTMLDivElement) => {
        while (target.firstChild) {
            target.removeChild(target.firstChild);
        }

        const workDrawingObject : iDrawingObject = {
            width : target.offsetWidth,
            height : target.offsetHeight,
            centerX : target.offsetWidth / 2,
            centerY : target.offsetHeight /2
        }

        workDrawingObject.paper = Raphael(target, workDrawingObject.width, workDrawingObject.height);

        setDrawingObject(workDrawingObject);
    }


    var workRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
    _InitRaphael(workRef.current as HTMLDivElement);

    return <div ref={workRef} className={classes.paperContainer}>{drawingObject.centerX}x{drawingObject.centerY}</div>
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is get the rendered DIV element and pass it to the _InitRaphael method, but it appears that this is called before the element is rendered.
Makes sense, but HOW could this be done. I've googled and googled and sometimes I run across the componentDidMount hook, but can thhat be used here and if thats the case then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `componentDidMount` because it could only be used in `class components`, when you use `function component`  as in your example use `hooks` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

I would recommend you to use the `useEffect` hook which imitates `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Both answers are similar so I'm tagging the first one as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the useEffect hook. It called after the rendering done so the ref should have value.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  _InitRaphael(workRef.current as HTMLDivElement);
}, [])
```

But unless you use an external non React library, you should not use this pattern. In a React app ref usage is the exception, not the normal way of dooing things.